# Drupal 7 TypeError for jQuery script: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have some JS code but Drupal 7 does not recognize it. I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Can anyone help me to make this script work? I'm using jQuery v1.4.4.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
this.screenshotPreview = function(){    
/* CONFIG */

    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 30;

    // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
    // you might want to adjust to get the right result

/* END CONFIG */
$("a.screenshot").hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    // this.title = "";    
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
    $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='"+ this.rel +"' alt='url preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
    $("#screenshot")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;    
    $("#screenshot").remove();
}); 
$("a.screenshot").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#screenshot")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
screenshotPreview('some text');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to include jQuery before your script.

Comment: jQuery is included at the top of scripts in the head

Comment: For code that's supposed to handle element, you may want to use Drupal.behaviors. See http://pbuyle.github.io/blog/2013/11/18/javascript-jquery-domready-drupal-7/ for a few explanations.

Answer (score 9):

Try changing all your instances of the "$" shortcut to "jQuery" and it should work. Calling the screenshotPreview function would for example then look like this:

```
// starting the script on page load
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
screenshotPreview('some text');
});
```

Alternatively enclose all your jQuery code in a function with jQuery as a parameter and the $ shortcut should then work.

```
// We define a function that takes one parameter named $.
(function ($) {
  // Use jQuery with the shortcut:
  console.log($.browser);
// Here we immediately call the function with jQuery as the parameter.
}(jQuery));
```

(Source: https://drupal.org/node/171213)

Comment: This is also explained quite well in jQuery's own documentation, in the chapter dedicated to writing plugins: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal 7 provides jQuery in the [no-conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), which means that `$` is not the `jQuery` object/namespace. This should not be an issue with properly written jQuery plugins that follow [jQuery's plugins authoring documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope).

JavaScript code that expect `$` to be the jQuery namespace will not work within a Drupal page. This can be easily solved by wrapping the code in an immediately invoked anonymous function that will alias the jQuery namespace to `$`:

```
(function($) {
    // Here $ is the jQuery namespace.
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (or let me know if that's not right - but it seems to work for me)

```
/*******************************************************************
*                    :: Define Your Functions ::
*******************************************************************/ 

(function ($) {
    removeAjaxLoader = function() {
        console.log('removeAjaxLoader');
        $('body').find('.ajax-loader').remove();
        $('body').find('.ajax-loader-icon').remove();
        return false;
    } //removeAjaxLoader

    addAjaxLoader = function() {
        console.log('addAjaxLoader');
        removeAjaxLoader();
        $('body').append('<div class="ajax-loader"></div><div class="ajax-loader-icon"></div>');
        return false;
    } //addAjaxLoader
}) (jQuery);

/*******************************************************************
*                        :: Ready Set Go ::
*******************************************************************/ 
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready complete');
        removeAjaxLoader();

    }); // document.ready
}) (jQuery);
```